# How to CURL via OS X Terminal while POSTing a string and a JSON array? It currently says my POST fields are empty or blank

Tags: json, macos, curl

I've researched this and I still can't quite get it right as it says my POST fields are not set or empty. So at a guess this would be a syntax problem?

I have two fields I'm trying to POST, one called "app_hash" which is a string and one called "data" which is a well formatted JSON array containing the data.

So far I have:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"app_hash":"ThisIsAnAppHash123456","data":"{schedule:{schedule_id:"93",round1:"0",round2:"0",round3:"0",round4:"0",start_prompt:"0",notify_taken:"0",notify_missed:"0"}}"}' https://myurl.com/app/save_settings.php --verbose
```

I have set error messages to be returned in JSON to help me diagnose the issue and it definitely says the PHP script I'm trying to CURL thinks that my POST fields are empty or blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you could explain why I haven't got it right yet it would justify the amount of time I've spent researching this haha. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely to be your use of the option `-d`, which doesn't do quite what one might guess.

The `-d` option is equivalent to the `--data-ascii` option, which *encodes* its argument before sending it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  What you want is to use `--data-binary`, which sends its argument unchanged.

Yes, I think the options are unfortunately named; yes, I think it's unfortunate that `--data-ascii` is the one abbreviated to `-d`; yes, this has caught me out on more than one occasion before.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go! So how do I set --data-binary?

Comment: Simply use `--data-binary` where now you've used `-d`.  Look at the output you get with `--verbose` (the output after `>`, which is what's sent to the server): after `--data-binary` it should be _exactly_ the `{"app_hash": ...}` contents.